# Is There Any Alleviating Defence in Intoxication While Driving

Tags: united-kingdom, driving, alcohol

Considering this hypothetical scenario:

A voluntarily intoxicated man (e.g. driving home from a bar) causes an accident which results in the death of the other driver.

Under UK law is there any mitigating circumstances involving impaired judgement resulting in driving under the influence? Considering I'm fairly sure it's an automatic murder charge - are there any considerations made as to the degree/sentence length?

A few sources seem to suggest there aren't any intoxication considerations but I can't find anything concrete that doesn't use jargon I'm unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 3):

On the contrary, voluntary intoxication is an *aggravating* factor in driving offences, particularly if the intoxicated driver causes the death of another person.

https://www.gov.uk/government/news/life-sentences-for-killer-drivers (2017 press release)

> increasing the maximum penalty for causing death by dangerous driving
>   from 14 years to life
>
> increasing the maximum penalty for causing death by careless driving
>   whilst under the influence of drink or drugs from 14 years to life
>
> creating a new offence of causing serious injury by careless driving

Sentencing Guidelines for causing death by dangerous driving

https://www.sentencingcouncil.org.uk/offences/crown-court/item/causing-death-by-dangerous-driving/

But causing a death by accident is not murder.

Comment: In addition, then driving while intoxicated [is an offence in itself](https://www.gov.uk/drink-driving-penalties), even if no accident occurs.